# What's assignable to what?

Tags: code-golf, graph-theory, classification

*[related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/61097/golf-me-an-oop)*

---

## What's assignable to what?

In this challenge you will be given two types, `A` and `B` and determine if `A` is assignable to `B`, `B` is assignable to `A`, or neither.

### The Type System

(I will use `t` to represent any type)

#### Basic Types

Basic types are represented by a single capital letter, such as `X`. They are basically classes.

- `X` is assignable to `Y` if `Y` is either the same as, or a parent class of `X`.

#### Intersection Types

Intersection types are represented by `intersect<X, Y>`, and can have any number of types between the `<`'s (e.g. `intersect<X, Y, Z, D, E>`).

- `t` is assignable to `intersect<X1, X2... Xn>` if `t` is assignable to all `X`.
- `intersect<X1, X2... Xn>` is assignable to `t` if any `X` is assignable to `t`.

#### Union Types

Union types are represented by `union<X, Y>` and can have any number of types between the `<`'s (e.g. `union<X, Y, Z, D, E>`).

- `t` is assignable to `union<X1, X2... Xn>` if `t` is assignable to any `X`.
- `union<X1, X2... Xn>` is assignable to `t` if all `X` are assignable to `t`.

---

### Input

You will receive as input:

- The class hierarchy. You may choose the method of input for the class hierarchy. You can input a representation of a tree, or each type with a list of its parents, or anything else that accurately represents the class hierarchy.
- Two types (input is flexible, as long as the notation is consistent you may receive these types however you like).

---

### Output

You will output one of three consistent and distinct values, call them `X`, `Y`, and `Z`. Given two types `A` and `B`, output `X` if `A` is assignable to `B`, output `Y` if `B` is assignable to `A` and output `Z` otherwise (If `A` is assignable to `B` and `B` is assignable to `A`, you may output `X`, `Y`, both, or a fourth value).

---

### Test Cases

Format:

```
# of types
[type, parents...]
[type, parents...]
Type a
Type b
```

---

```
2
[A,B]
[B]
A
B
--
A is assignable to B


3
[A,B,C]
[B,C]
[C]
intersect<A,C>
A
--
A is assignable to intersect<A,C>


3
[A,B,C]
[B,C]
[C]
union<A,C>
A
--
A is assignable to union<A,C>


3
[A,B,C]
[B,C]
[C]
intersect<B,C>
A
--
A is assignable to intersect<B,C>


3
[A,B,C]
[X,Y,Z]
[T,U,V]
intersect<union<A,T,X>,intersect<A,B>,Y>
intersect<T,C,X>
--
intersect<T,C,X> and intersect<union<A,T,X>,intersect<A,B>,Y> are not assignable to each other    

1
[A]
A
A
--
A is assignable to A


3
[A,B,C]
[X,Y,Z]
[T,U,V]
intersect<A,intersect<A,B>,Y>
intersect<T,C,X>
--
intersect<T,C,X> and intersect<A,intersect<A,B>,Y> are not assignable to each other


2
[A]
[B]
A
B
--
B and A are not assignable to each other

3
[A,B,C]
[X,Y,Z]
[T,U,V]
intersect<union<A,X>,intersect<A,B>,Y>
intersect<T,C,X>
--
intersect<T,C,X> and intersect<union<A,X>,intersect<A,B>,Y> are not assignable to each other
```

[Here is a link to a working ungolfed Java solution you can use for testing](https://tio.run/##7VhLb@M2EL7rVzA@7FKIV0h6jO2gSS4tuukWSIoeDB8omYnpyJRKUtmku/7t6fAhWQ9Kjt091kBiizOcN78Zak2eyacsp3y9fHp7Y5s8EwqtYTEqFEujKyHI62cm1STw06SH8AuRq1uSeyg9kvzMdwnhnAofRZHkaRIEeRGnLEFJSqREt4Rx9C0IEHwYV1Q8kISi@9ecom8ozrKUEo6AkT1yEqf0PsOGlqkVFeEEbe1OqYiqRF4TCb9BfUo3lCvppBlG/ckFeyaKIu3W1DBfopwIzTrpMCUrIhAnGzoJdjTrgNmKPVLGu11hTa/@qBWTkWNDs67aikdvBgaruaRsOzbUtT9S9YeVh9tqBVWF4A3tQ1KN@SDud9A@KKvXvJ@/PFMh2JK2Re9LaUsZe0DYEKA4IMk8odmDDXybs20a/bsgqcRO6vfvDeejJOMKKq@kNxOwRTSV1K/7V12jkibKp/8hE8g684IuEMY1ZqsngqBqOmTIt7/0@MTY2gjRS@@GmuMP4DGdeLm2wf6VMnyioO8PyJ@cZfw9wXCMBwXiyDh0PTgiDJ5gboP9fIccAlejX@I11AjKfMWvI4Bmsy5xOGHdQ6SF8CJN9VGA4N9oqISzfQKio93zgBZvPBqPFnhj83@GsDum2STwhc0C3MyyHwEk0CzQClrWTbbsxSgMTKEfQ7ftlnNbpIqZcqUvivJlp20YqNVrBmld8U7qwhpdqDr77U40rqnqaUpWi9Iqum2nEozbvN5mYyiQDidtTytp@zeA/f0CfxT4NxFkp9RXpLrGX5pQYWX2wcUgVGyPPfa@SjDA96OrwAj9vwLajfOYEujpmtshqPNWT7MGyly6WjBewPghKb5TgvFHkw8oA5JPb2DeIgkc6zFys5ypnKafphvAlggECiX/YmqFR6wEg5Gdcdr0QpfJqBMBM4pPqwp01aPnTfrVES9xayrSgMv4kr4A21kL07@uWEo13Gry1JqRUv4IJoR9uRrwZWwV9SbOWBvlhVxhbfAOEfVTdfnRLoShfw6wlp7OUE1rZTE6ReeeetgNQT1hPtBse4SPMNlqO9BcPdNfKZuiUDfej5cfB0cvY6xk/@jueonOh8YuU9uqhJgoz3Lc40QtDJQ@4focGJHlEqvwvXNbIyRH@T/u93@/3MEMe11zR1oveyzam/XzIxGqZlENqXxOuB19dp7VTdw2kM5iuwO654wt0QYuVw7n5gtExGMDytw7AiTdt8Md@4TvXqWim4jxmj4NPklWcF1kblfEYVCDo1/3q076zDit0waB1png3oE0wc80IYN@Bvnga2ptgZ@np11orcC9ZWvbIOcXxCfXSALc9t0MIIugZGODL2iewniKR3OAl9Eo3C0s9MICVmSeMoVHY4D5aENyF/aLC/jamJX7TIdJok@XSNayGanMKGzb5Mb4SecOUVZGeXn@jb5irOWF1oP52cKLfTG4Vq@q9h7vZdMvRifJvnfp4OYYDcvVn9KKvFA4NpeOMYrDwUtNlf010ocQvqZWg8NfWOkWwbsjtl70dou4elnRRo@OhANRyiZYFocFdL3ogah6UEGoCyv86uFvOubn6xvAa8lxB02SPces5It7@IJGFyP2rRxMaZKMqzFs0mSKd0xxnakxq5HmKBp3hzCLc1mhIpgVuUo56IRmPkJw5d/tRSqDpVNwoIO/paq4qYq8S1U8oIr0qjrpuIU@fEAn/8ECwpdOqX0UFPFMtayiJFnZK8Io9A3c2@Dt7adgfjW@XgRz@LsKrv8F) (it takes input in the same way as the test cases)

---

This is code-golf, so least bytes in each language wins for that language!

Comment: [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges/14085#14085) (deleted)

Comment: @ovs no, A has parents B and C.

Comment: @HalvardHummel apologies; I've edited the post

Comment: Will inherit form a circle?

Comment: What should output if both A is assignable to B and B is assignable to A?

Comment: Will any intersection / union contain at least 2 types?

Comment: @tsh As stated in the main post, if A->B and B->A you may output `X`, `Y`, or both... you may also output a fourth value if its easier. Also, an intersection/union *could* contain a single type.

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 177 bytes

`c` is a dictionary of the parents of each type, `a` and `b` are the two expression to check. Types are represented by strings, while intersects and unions are represented by lists with of expressions, with the first element set to `0`for intersect and `1` for union

Returns `0` if they are not assignable to each other, `1` if `a` is assignable to `b`, `2` if `b` is assignable to `a` and `3` if both are assignable to each other

```python
lambda c,a,b:y(a,b,c)+2*y(b,a,c)
y=lambda a,b,c:(b in c[a]or a==b if b[0]in c else[all,any][b[0]](y(a,x,c)for x in b[1:]))if a[0]in c else[any,all][a[0]](y(x,b,c)for x in a[1:])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##vZKxbsIwEIZ3nsLyZLc3hHaLlAF4hYAA18M5JSpSahBliIX67OmdTVJVDG2qqovj/P99d39OOYbzy8E/dnXx1DX46p5RVIDg8qDohErfP9wF5Uiq9CQU15Jo5cqJvReVQXs4CSwKeq2FM5llVeyat53BpgH0wRqWreKmLXWqCWgZdmaaW62Jw6@cD0CsNXjl2hhm4DBy3fG092dVq4ucydzIubRAR27sO5DCd60nN0UgF31hui0SYrJERW02Dp3@Hs3g0/0W7TmQa/Y25G3Z2yRxmx4le0vyVuwtk7ga5vVpS8lt7PDh89QpCWUcGwtuMvX7/Z@4PGp8xJF/wp8u9mdL7T4A)

Answer (score 3):

### JavaScript (ES6), 138 bytes

```
(p,a,b,g=(a,b)=>a==b||(p[a]||a.i||a.u||[])[a.u?'every':'some'](t=>g(t,b))||(b.i||b.u||[])[b.i?'every':'some'](t=>g(a,t)))=>g(a,b)||+g(b,a)
```

`p` is the parent map, which is a JavaScript object whose keys are the types with parents and whose values are arrays of parent(s). For example, if there are two types `A` and `B` and `B` is the parent of `A` then `p` would be `{A:['B']}`.

Intersection types are represented in `a` and `b` as a JavaScript object with a key of `i` whose value is an array of types, while union types have a key of `u`. For example, the intersection of two types `A` and `B` would be `{i:['A','B']}`.

The return value is `true` if `a` is assignable to `b`, `1` if `a` is not assignable to `b` but `b` is assignable to `a`, or `0` if neither is assignable to each other.

Answer (score 2):

## C++17, 595 bytes

```cpp
#include<type_traits>
#define p(x)template<class...T>class x;
#define d(a,b)disjunction<s<a,b>...>{};
#define c(a,b)conjunction<s<a,b>...>{};
#define u(x)u<x...>
#define i(x)i<x...>
#define k struct s
#define e ...A
#define t(a,b)template<class a,class b>
using namespace std;p(i)p(u)t(B,D)k:disjunction<is_base_of<B,D>,is_same<B,D>>{};t(a,e)k<a,u(A)>:d(a,A)t(a,e)k<a,i(A)>:c(a,A)t(a,e)k<u(A),a>:c(A,a)t(a,e)k<i(A),a>:d(A,a)t(e,...B)k<i(A),i(B)>:d(A,i(B))t(e,...B)k<u(A),u(B)>:c(A,u(B))t(e,...B)k<i(A),u(B)>:d(A,u(B))t(e,...B)k<u(A),i(B)>:c(A,u(B))t(A,B)int f=s<A,B>::value?-1:s<B,A>::value?1:0;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hZJRb8IgFIWf119B4kuJaOYrIkvrfoIuuheDlJo7K20EFjfjX5@Dqm01S/Yk5zvnXnKKsqoGGynP5x5oWbhMMftVqZXdC7CGR71M5aAVquIDtmpXFcIqJgthzHA4nPH6hA7jJpfFgqxxBubDaWmh1MwwT7hP8@Opzck6J0v9T875ex07BNww8Awe2BYZu3fSItMghXwiaaStb7zvgAS5/K555AzoDdJip0wlpPL7snEVA65ih22ckle8pd1eYFZrYdSqzJk3OfHa@OFahArhPoW3vpWLE8xp@DIJbinUVN7RkCQi0ISIhsKVZleqiC@W3gyIU3zxwqlr19tcbYeF7sGG1s7@sF27vDOdkBSDtiifGObPnNJPUTj1MhhR46snDRjR53Hzn0IMSv8@Sux4FKZ3AnSMj9HT9dHS8OQ3Me2KZVe8d8W8K966IqEpuVuyoEtyNzujc3IbySiVpbOIMZQz8KWgLkaWnDg2I1Oy4Hz8FJ2i84/MC7Ex54Efmsh@f/T9Cw)

A variable template `f` that accepts as input some types and intersection `i<...>` or union `u<...>` of them and returns `-1` if `A` is assignable to `B`  and `1` if `B` is assignable to `A` and `0` otherwise.

**Ungolfed:**

```cpp
#include <type_traits>
using namespace std;

template<class...T>class Intersect;
template<class...T>class Union;

template<class A,class B>
struct is_assignable_to:
    disjunction<is_base_of<A,B>,is_same<A,B>>{};

template<class a,class...A>
struct is_assignable_to<a,Union<A...>>:
    disjunction<is_assignable_to<a,A>...>{};

template<class a,class...A>
struct is_assignable_to<a,Intersect<A...>>:
    conjunction<is_assignable_to<a,A>...>{};

template<class a,class...A>
struct is_assignable_to<Union<A...>,a>:
    conjunction<is_assignable_to<A,a>...>{};

template<class a,class...A>
struct is_assignable_to<Intersect<A...>,a>:
    disjunction<is_assignable_to<A,a>...>{};

template<class...A,class...B>
struct is_assignable_to<Intersect<A...>,Intersect<B...>>:
    disjunction<is_assignable_to<A,Intersect<B...>>...>{};

template<class...A,class...B>
struct is_assignable_to<Union<A...>,Union<B...>>:
    conjunction<is_assignable_to<A,Union<B...>>...>{};

template<class...A,class...B>
struct is_assignable_to<Intersect<A...>,Union<B...>>:
    disjunction<is_assignable_to<A,Union<B...>>...>{};

template<class...A,class...B>
struct is_assignable_to<Union<A...>,Intersect<B...>>:
    conjunction<is_assignable_to<A,Intersect<B...>>...>{};

template <class A,class B>
int f = is_assignable_to<A,B>::value?-1:is_assignable_to<B,A>::value?1:0;
```

**Usage:**

```cpp
#include <iostream>
int main(){
    struct B{};
    struct C{};
    struct Y{};
    struct Z{};
    struct U{};
    struct V{};
    struct A:B,C{};
    struct X:Y,Z{};
    struct T:U,V{};
    std::cout << f<Intersect<A,Intersect<A,B>,Y>,Union<T,C,X>>; 
}
```